# Xcode failed to load libvulkan.1.dylib

Tags: xcode, macos, vulkan, moltenvk

I am setting up dev env for Vulkan on OS X,via MoltenVK wrapper. I use Xcode IDE.

1. I downloaded VulkanSDK from lunarG website.
2. Configured the includes.
3. Added (copied) `libvulkan.1.1.121.dylib` ,`libvulkan.1.dylib` into the project
   ,then added those into **Build Phases** -> **Link Binary With Libraries** of the target.

The sample code is:

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

VkInstance instance;
void createInstance() {
   VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
   appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
   appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
   appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 1, 0);
   appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
   appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 1, 0);
   appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_1;

   VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
   createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
   createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

   uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
   const char** glfwExtensions;
   glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

   createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = glfwExtensionCount;
   createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwExtensions;

   createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;

   if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS)
   {
    printf("failed to create instance!");
   }
}


 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    createInstance();
    return 0;
 }
```

I receive no linker errors.

When I launch the app, I keep getting:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libvulkan.1.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VulkanApp-aybsxkpxiqbshfebkfpcwaoiuige/Build/Products/Debug/VulkanApp
>   Reason: image not found

Then Xcode presents me with the following disassembly:

[image]

My hardware setup is:

MacBook Pro. macOS 10.14.6

Two GPUs:

1. Radeon Pro 555
2. Intel HD Graphics 630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue and the solution for me was to clear the content of Subpath in Xcode -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Copy files.[image]